# Windows service recovery - run a program wont work

Tags: batch-file, windows-services

How do i do this?

i've tried all i can think of.

- Browsing for my .exe file i want to run.
- run a bat file
- writing forcedos.exe in program textbox and path to my bat file in command line parameters textbox

Why cant it just work with an normal exe?

and i know it should run a program because it can restart the service correctly.

**EDIT**

```
Application: test.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.Exception
```

[image]

This is my latest try to make it work.

the script has the code

```
Dim objShell
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
objShell.Run("iexplore")
Set objShell = Nothing
```

Now the script opens internet explorer if i run the cmd command

```
wscript.exe "C:\asfh.vbs"
```

Comment: Thank you, i will try on Super User.

Comment: If you do post to Super User, you need to make it clearer what it is you're trying to do and why.  (I have no idea what "windows service recovery" is supposed to mean.)

Comment: its a tab if you press properties on an windows service.

Comment: So you're trying to make the system run a program when a particular service fails?  If this is your service (i.e., one you wrote yourself) the question might be on-topic here after all.  You understand that the program that runs won't be able to directly interact with the user?  Have you checked the event log for error messages?

Comment: @HarryJohnston Yes it is my own windows service, but i understand the service itself cant interact with the user, but i taught the os does that for me when i set "Run a program" at the first failure. i cant see the difference between the os knowing when my app crashes and restarts and crashes and starts that script.

Comment: I don't know whether Internet Explorer is capable of running in a service context.  Have you tried running a script that does something simpler, like writing to a log file?  An event simpler approach would be to set cmd.exe as the program to run, with no arguments.  You can then use Task Manager to see whether cmd.exe got launched or not.

Comment: Thank you! i was able to use something more simple and i got the script to work!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "run a program" recovery option for when a service crashes runs the specified executable in the same way as the service, i.e., it runs in session 0 (and so is affected by [session 0 isolation](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-US?query=session%200%20isolation&emptyWatermark=true&ac=4), see also [related questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=session%200%20isolation)) and it runs with the same security context as the service.

This means that it can't interact directly with the user (you can display a GUI, but nobody will see it) but it also restricts what the executable or script can do.  For example, some shell API functions will not work properly unless the user account has been interactively logged in at some point.  In the example script you posted, the script itself is probably running, but is unable to launch Internet Explorer because IE is only designed to run in an interactive session.

Provided you restrict yourself to basic functionality, it should all work as expected.  (There is no master list that I know of describing what functionality is safe to use in a service context, but it is usually easy to guess.  You can resort to trial and error if necessary!)

Also note that as far as I know `forcedos.exe` is no longer present in modern versions of Windows.  If you want to run a batch file, you can specify `cmd.exe` as the application and `/c myscript.bat` as the command line parameters.

Comment: thats very helpful with the forcedos.exe information, iäve spent much time trying that angle. Thank you for your help, like i said in my comment earlier i got an simple script to work and read two files i prepare beforehand and email me the content. this way i know which customer and which versions of my software they have to i can contact and help them.